# Selecting from two table using joins

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, ms-access

Table 1 Color

[image]

and another table favorite Color

[image: Table of Color]

Now i want the out put as

[image]

How can I get this

Comment: are you using all RDBMS you tagged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT f.favColorID,
c.Color,
CASE WHEN c.colorid = f.colorid THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END IsFavorite
FROM tblColours c, tblFavColours f
ORDER BY 1
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8be49/8)

Have a look at using [CASE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

Comment: you should consider that user can favorite multiple colors.

Comment: I don't think the output is same as in the question.

Comment: @astander yes now seems perfect

Answer (score 1):

I can give you the answer in T-SQL dialect (Microsoft SQL-Server). The `case when` part might be different in other dialects.

```
select f.favColorID,
       c.Color,
       case when f.ColorID=c.ColorID then 'YES' else 'NO' end as IsFavorite
from   colors c
       cross join favoriteColor f
order by f.favColorID
```